# Aggregate pipeline with updateOne

Tags: mongodb

Below is my code to update currentQuantity of stock document.

for an example;

***Instance 1***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 10
therefore diff_qty = 10-5 = 5;
```

***Instance 2***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 3
therefore diff_qty = 3- 5 = (-)2;
```

***Instance 3***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 5
therefore diff_qty = 5- 5 = 0;
```

I have written the code to cover all these instances inside $switch. See below.

```
    import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { body } from 'express-validator';
import {
  requireAuth,
  validateRequest,
  NotFoundError,
  currentUser,
  AccessRestrictedError,
} from '@ssomlk-org/distribution-common';

import { LoadingSheet } from '../../models/LoadingSheet';
import { Stock } from '../../models/Stock';

const router = express.Router();

router.put(
  '/api/loading-sheets/:id',
  [
    body('area')
      .trim()
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('Loading sheet must have an area'),
    body('territory')
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('Loading sheet must have a territory'),
    body('route')
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('Loading sheet must have a route'),
    body('records').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Loading sheet must have data'),
  ],
  validateRequest,
  currentUser,
  requireAuth,
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
      throw new NotFoundError('Loading Sheet Not Found');
    }

    const { records } = req.body;
    const agency: any = req.currentUser!.agency;

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction({
      readPreference: 'primary',
      readConcern: { level: 'local' },
      writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
    });

    const existingLoadingSheet = await LoadingSheet.findById(
      req.params.id
    ).session(session);

    if (!existingLoadingSheet) {
      session.endSession();
      throw new NotFoundError('Loading Sheet Not Found');
    }

    if (existingLoadingSheet.get('agency')._id != agency) {
      session.endSession();
      throw new AccessRestrictedError();
    }

    const oldLoadingsheetStockValuesArray = [...existingLoadingSheet?.records];
    const oldLoadingsheetStockValuesObj = oldLoadingsheetStockValuesArray.reduce(
      function (result, item) {
        var key = item.stockId;
        result[key] = {
          loadingCaseCount: item.loadingCaseCount,
          loadingUnitCount: item.loadingUnitCount,
          loadingTotal: item.loadingTotal,
          stockId: item.stockId,
          product: item.product,
          index: item.index,
          batchNo: item.batchNo,
          type: item.type,
        };
        return result;
      },
      {}
    );

    try {
      existingLoadingSheet.set({ records, isUnloaded: false });
      await existingLoadingSheet.save({ session: session });

      for (const el of records) {
        const oldLoadingTotal =
          oldLoadingsheetStockValuesObj[el.stockId] != null
            ? oldLoadingsheetStockValuesObj[el.stockId].loadingTotal
            : 0;
        const diff_qty = el.loadingTotal - oldLoadingTotal;
        await Stock.updateOne(
          {
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(el.stockId),
            agency,
          },
          [
            {
              $set: {
                currentQuantity: {
                  $add: [
                    '$currentQuantity',
                    {
                      $switch: {
                        branches: [
                          {
                            case: { $gt: [diff_qty, 0] },
                            then: {
                              $cond: [
                                { $gte: ['$currentQuantity', diff_qty] },
                                -diff_qty,
                                0, //revert the loading sheet record total back to previous Qty
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                          {
                            case: { $lt: [diff_qty, 0] },
                            then: { $abs: diff_qty },
                          },
                        ],
                        default: 0,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $set: {
                unitQuantity: {
                  $mod: ['$currentQuantity', el.units],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $set: {
                caseQuantity: {
                  $floor: {
                    $divide: ['$currentQuantity', el.units],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          { session: session }
        );
      }

      await session.commitTransaction();
      session.endSession();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      await session.abortTransaction();
      session.endSession();
      throw new Error(
        `Error occured while trying to update the loading sheet. ${error}`
      );
    }

    const response = {
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        sheet: existingLoadingSheet,
      },
    };

    res.send(response);
  }
);

export { router as updateLoadingSheetRouter };
```

In any of the cases my stock will be updated.
As in if my currentQty = 10;

***Instance 1***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 10
therefore diff_qty = 10-5 = 5; // Request 5 more items from the stock

then currentQty = 10 - 5 = 5;
```

***Instance 2***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 3
therefore diff_qty = 3- 5 = (-)2; // 2 items are returned back to the warehouse so it needs to be added back to stock

then currentQty = 10 + 2 = 2;
```

***Instance 3***

```
previously requested stock qty = 5;
newly requested stock qty = 5
therefore diff_qty = 5- 5 = 0;

then currentQty = 10 + 0 = 10;
```

I want to identify the update which happened in Instance 1, and Instance 2.
But not Instance 3 even thought it was updated from currentQty 10 => 10 and there is no effect in that update.

Is there any way i could achieve this in the aggregate pipeline itself? Your thoughts would be really helpful

Cheers

***Example of a document***

```
{
_id:6007840db033b20019efac87
caseQuantity:4
unitQuantity:395
totalQuantity:2000
currentQuantity:1995
isClaimActive:"true"
claim:32
status:"Active"
purchaseInventoryId:6007840bb033b20019efac86
index"1611105277028"
batchNo:1
unitPrice:14.19
casePrice:255.75
product:5f8d9a6184c1d0005814ed61
productName:"Red Cow - Red Cow 18g"
type:5f8d931fcc42160023d770e2
units:400
agency:5f8d6f0acc42160023d770c4
createdBy:5f8d6f2dcc42160023d770c5
__v:0
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear, `previously requested stock qty` is this field in your collection? `newly requested stock qty` is this your input that is `diff_qty` can you post sample document.

Comment: previously requested stock qty = oldLoadingsheetStockValuesObj[el.stockId].loadingTotal & diff_qty = el.loadingTotal - oldLoadingTotal; 

I have updated the code @turivishal. Check above

Comment: what is the problem? i have tested all 3 instances all are working as per your input and expected output.

Comment: I want to identify the update which happened in Instance 1, and Instance 2. But not Instance 3 even thought it was updated from currentQty 10 => 10 and there is no effect in that update. When using updateOne it returns ok for all the 3 instances. This is correct. 

But i want to excusitely know if that update did a change in the value (e.g: 5 -> 10 or 5 -> 3) 5 -> 5 is not a real update

Answer (score 0):

You can't select both version like before update and after update, There are few options,

1. [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), there are properties,

- `new: true` to select updated document
- `returnOriginal: false` to select old/original document that was before update

```
await Stock.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(el.stockId),
    agency
  },
  [{ // your code }],
  { 
    new: true
    // or 
    // returnOriginal: false
  }
)
```

2. `findOne()` and `save()`, find document, update document and save changes,

```
// SELECT
await Stock.findOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(el.stockId),
    agency
}, function (err, stockDoc) {
   
    if(err) console.error('ERROR!');
   
    // ADD/CONVERT YOUR STOCK QUANTITY CALCULATION FOR CLIENT SIDE
    stockDoc.currentQuantity = // something calculated value;
    // ... your other fields
    
    // SAVE 
    stockDoc.save(function (err) {
        if(err) console.error('ERROR!');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @turivishal. If the same record is being updated by 2 different users will that affect when using findOne()?? Will it cause concurrent issues??

Comment: yes definitely there are possibilities concurrent issues, you can go with first option.